# Selecting N rows from each group in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to search for the updates sent by the friends of a giving user.

There is a table called `friendship`. It has a column called `profile1` and another one called `profile2`. It represents the friendship between two users in this websystem, and a friendship is the presence of two giving ids, no matter in what position. So the profile with id 1 may have 2 friends, profile with id 2 and with id 3 as following:

```
friendship           
profile1 profile2            
1         2 <--                
3         1 <--        
2         5
...
```

Now I want to search for the **updates** sent by some user's friends. There is this table `update`

```
update
id  content  time  profile
1   A text   ...   2
2   A text   ...   2
3   A text   ...   3
4   A text   ...   2
5   A text   ...   3
6   A text   ...   2
7   A text   ...   10
8   A text   ...   11
```

If my profile/user is identified by the id 1, and it has only 2 friends (the profiles identified by id 2 and 3) and also I need my search to return only 2 results by each user, my SELECT has to return updates 1,2,3 and 5.

Preferably updates should be grouped by its author and it would be great if I could set the number of different profiles to be considered in this search (for example, if profile 1 had 10 friends and I wanted only updates from 3 profiles, the most recent must appear first).

Do you know how can I achieve this??

thank you very much!

@EDIT

This returns all updates sent by friends of profile 1. But i'm not sure whether or not i'm in the right direction

```
SELECT u.*
FROM  `update` u
INNER JOIN friendship f1 ON f1.profile1 = u.author
WHERE f1.profile2 =1
UNION 
SELECT u.* 
FROM  `update` u
INNER JOIN friendship f2 ON f2.profile2 = u.author
WHERE f2.profile1 =1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to do it in two queries, you can do it like this. First, get three profiles who have most recently posted based on your constraints:

```
-- Get the three latest updated profiles from here.
-- (we can't use a CTE because MySQL doesn't support
-- them yet).
SELECT DISTINCT p.profile FROM 
  (
    SELECT ui.profile, ui.time  FROM
    (
      SELECT u.profile, u.time 
      FROM `update` u 
      INNER JOIN `friendship` f ON f.profile2 = u.profile 
      WHERE f.profile1 = 1 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT u.profile, u.time 
      FROM `update` u 
      INNER JOIN `friendship` f ON f.profile1 = u.profile 
      WHERE f.profile2 = 1
    ) ui ORDER BY ui.time DESC 
  ) p LIMIT 0, 3;
```

From that query, get the three profile IDs out and put them in place of `<id1>`, `<id2>` and `<id3>` in the following query

```
-- Use a union to get the result set back
(SELECT a.content, a.time, a.profile FROM `update` a
WHERE a.profile = <id1>
ORDER BY a.time DESC
LIMIT 0, 2)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a.content, a.time, a.profile FROM `update` a
WHERE a.profile = <id2>
ORDER BY a.time DESC
LIMIT 0, 2)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a.content, a.time, a.profile FROM `update` a
WHERE a.profile = <id3>
ORDER BY a.time DESC
LIMIT 0, 2);
```

If you get less than three profiles back, either remove parts of the query in your PHP code, or set the WHERE clause to something like 0 so it always evaluates to fault (assuming you don't have a profile ID of zero)

The 2 in the limit clauses above can be changed if you want more or fewer results per profile.

Sample SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22e57/1 (updated fiddle to make the content more meaningful and to use times)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing a series of queries for each author within one transaction, that way there would not be a need for grouping - you could simply append results together outside of your SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `update` WHERE 
    profile IN (SELECT profile2 FROM `friendship` WHERE profile1=1) OR
    profile IN (SELECT profile1 FROM `friendship` WHERE profile2=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68400/13/0)

```
SELECT T1.profile,T1.content,T1.time
FROM
    (SELECT UPD.profile,UPD.content,UPD.time,
           IF (@prevProfile != UPD.profile,@timeRank:=1,@timeRank:=@timeRank+1) as timeRank,
           @prevProfile := UPD.profile
    FROM
         (SELECT UP.profile,UP.content,UP.time
         FROM
            (SELECT profile,max(time) as latestUpdateTime
             FROM friendship F INNER JOIN updates U
             ON (F.profile1 = 1 AND U.profile = profile2) /* <-- specify profile on this line */
             OR(F.profile2 = 1 AND U.profile = profile1)  /* <-- specify profile on this line */
             GROUP BY profile
             ORDER BY latestUpdateTime DESC
             LIMIT 3 /* limit to 3 friends profiles that have the most recent updates */
             )as LU
          INNER JOIN updates UP
          ON (UP.profile = LU.profile)
          ORDER BY profile,time DESC
          )as UPD,(SELECT @prevProfile:=0,@timeRank:=0)variables
     )T1
WHERE T1.timeRank BETWEEN 1 AND 2 /* grab 2 lastest updates for each profile */      
ORDER BY T1.time DESC
```

in my example, profile id 1 has more than 3 friends, but i am only grabbing 3 friends that made the most recent updates.

explanation of above query.

`LU` grabs 3 profiles that are friends with profile id 1 that made the latest updates.

`UPD` grabs all contents that belong to these 3 friends.

`T1` returns the contents along with a `timeRank` number for each content in order from 1 counting upward order by `time DESCENDING` for each profile

and finally the WHERE we only grab 2 content updates for each profile

then we finally ORDER these updates based on TIME starting from most recent.